# Verse in Beamer frame

Tags: beamer, verse

how can I archive  numbered poem lines in a beamer frame?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{verse}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \poemlines{2}
        \begin{block}{essen}
            \begin{verse}
                Sunset and evening star, \\
                  And one clear call for me! \\
                And may there be no moaning of the bar, \\
                  When I put out to sea, \\!
            \end{verse}
        \end{block}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I think, the line numbers are too far in the right, but I don't know how to handle the problem.

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of the lines of a numbered poem is in the right margin. You can use `columns` to reduce the line width and simulate the margins:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{verse}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \poemlines{2}
  \begin{block}{essen}
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
      \column{.9\linewidth}
      \begin{verse}
        Sunset and evening star, \\
        And one clear call for me! \\
        And may there be no moaning of the bar, \\
        When I put out to sea, \\!
      \end{verse}
      \column{.1\linewidth}
    \end{columns}
  \end{block}

  \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    \column{.9\linewidth}
    \begin{block}{essen}
      \begin{verse}
        Sunset and evening star, \\
        And one clear call for me! \\
        And may there be no moaning of the bar, \\
        When I put out to sea, \\!
      \end{verse}
    \end{block}
    \column{.1\linewidth}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: great, thank you!